# 35' RV entering Yosemite on a Day Use Entry Ticket via the Tioga Pass, where should we plan to stop the night before?

Tags: motor-homes, yosemite

I'll be driving a 35-foot motorhome from Lake Tahoe via Lee Vining (going around the forest fire if needed), planning to enter Yosemite via the Tioga Pass and exiting at Mariposa/Oakhurst.

I was able to secure a Day Pass reservation for the park, but it's for the last day of my vacation, so I'll be able to use only the first of three days. So to make the most of it, I'd like to start driving at sunrise and enter the park as early in the day as possible.

I've been researching all the campgrounds near the Tioga Pass entrance and they all seem to have a max length of 30' and/or they do not accept reservations.

So my question for you folks with some "street smarts" and experience in the Tioga Pass - Lee Vining corridor, what's the best plan here if my goal is to overnight as close as possible to the park entrance?

RV is fully self-contained so I'm open to boondocking, BLM, rest areas, etc.

My park reservation is for a Saturday, so arriving anywhere on Friday night without a reservation is going to be rough.

Comment: A good question is how strongly the 30 feet limit is enforced. It definitely wouldn’t be a problem in many camping sites I’ve seen.

Comment: @JonathanReez, on the other hand, it's a hard limit in others: if you try to fit a 35-foot RV into a 30-foot campground, you'll end up with one bumper up against a tree, and the other hanging out into the street.

Comment: As far as boondocking, there is an extensive network of dirt roads in the Inyo National Forest to the southeast of Lee Vining, many with random turnouts and campsites.  I just passed through there on CA-120 which seems pretty lightly traveled.  Not sure how passable they'd be for your RV though.